# Código para imprimir los 100 primeros números primos

Tags: java

Necesito un código que me muestre los 100 primeros números primos, estoy empezando en este mundo y quiero aprender gracias.

Tengo este código para imprimir los primos de 1 al 100

```java
public class Primos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean primo;
        System.out.println("Son números primos del 1 al 100:\n");
        // Estructura for
        for (int num = 2; num <= 100; num++) {
            primo = true;
            for (int i = num - 1; i > 1; i--) {
                if (num % i == 0) {
                    primo = false;
                    break;
                }//fin if
            }//fin for
            if (primo) {
                System.out.println(num + " es primo");
            }//fin if
        }//fin for

    }//fin main

}//fin clase
```

Comment: y cuál es el problema con este código?

Comment: No me muestra los primeros 100 números primos, solo me muestra del 1 al 100

Comment: Pues tienes un for que va hasta el 100, ahí nunca vas a pasar de 100.  Tampoco tiene sentido validar desde el número -1, con validar desde num/2 es suficiente porque es imposible la división entera por algo menor que 2 y mayor que 1

Answer (score 1):

Respecto al problema que tienes, esto es debido a que estás realizando un for que se encuentra evaluando los números primos que se encuentran desde el 1 al 100. Para ser más exactos, es el primer for del código.
Para solucionar tu problema, solo se debe remplazar el primer for por un bucle while el cual funcione como un contador de números primos, tal que, si el número de primos obtenidos es mayor a 100, este se detenga.
La solución seguiría siguiente:

```
    //Declaración de variables
    int contadorPrimos = 0;
    int num=2;
    boolean primo;

    //Usamos un bucle while que solo se detendrá si ya han sido impresos 100 números primos
    while(contadorPrimos<100){
      primo = true;
      for (int i = num -1; i>1; i--){
        if (num % i == 0){
          primo = false;
          break;
        }//fin if
      }//fin for
      if (primo) {
        System.out.println(num + " es primo");
        contadorPrimos++; //Debido a que obtuvimos un número primo, el contador aumentará
        //El ciclo while terminará cuando obtengamos 100 números primos
      }
      num++; //Aumenta en +1 el respectivo número a evaluar si será primo o no.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Con solo pequeñas modificaciones tu código funciona.

```
 public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.out.println( "Son números primos del 1 al 100:\n" );
    boolean primo;
    int primos = 0;  // agregamos un contador de primos
    for( int num = 2; primos < 100; num++ ) { // usamos de condición el contador de primos
        primo = true;
        for( int i = num - 1; i > 1; i-- ) {
            if( num % i == 0 ) {
                primo = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( primo ) {
            System.out.println( num + " es primo" );
            primos++;  // aumentamos el contador
        }
    }

}
```